# Error al obtener datos en Angular con HTTP

Tags: angular

Tengo un pequeño problema, estoy intentando acceder a una API creada por mi en Java mediante un proyecto de Angular. El problema lo tengo cuando quiero recuperar una información en concreto, una ruta que tengo marcada por defecto en una clase de Java, para mostrarla por pantalla.

El problema está en que aunque llame al método que obtiene esa ruta lo primero de todo, el resto de componentes carga antes de que se obtenga la ruta, por lo tanto no se muestra por pantalla por que no le da tiempo a obtenerla. Sospecho que la solución estaría en poner el método como *Async*, pero no estoy seguro de si es la solución ni de cómo se hace.

El método lo cargo en el constructor de la pagina de la siguiente forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hago un `console.log` para ver que se carga después la ruta.

El método original del *service* es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la consola se puede ver el orden de carga de los componentes:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Claro, al terminar de cargar lo último de todo el método, no se visualiza la ruta por pantalla, que es lo que necesito. ¿Alguna idea?

---

### EDITO:

Con la aclaración de abajo por parte de *Lobos* me sale el siguiente error. Lo pongo por aquí para que sea más visual:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CoreService } from '../../services/core.service';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-index',
  templateUrl: './index.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./index.component.css']
})

export class IndexComponent implements OnInit {

  pathPadre = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');

  constructor(public coreService: CoreService, private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {

    this.coreService.cargarRutas();
    this.coreService.pathPadre.subscribe(ruta =>this.pathPadre = ruta);  
  }
}
```

El error me salta en la parte de `ruta =>this.pathPadre = ruta`, con la siguiente información:

> ```
> (property) IndexComponent.pathPadre: BehaviorSubject<string>
> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'BehaviorSubject<string>'.ts(2322)
> ```

Comment: Por qué estás cargando las cosas en el constructor ?

Comment: Me da igual cargarlo ahí que en el *ngOnInit()*. La cosa es que necesito cargarlo para poder hacer uso de la información que me viene, y así poder visualizarla por pantalla cuando carga la página.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agrego servicio modificado y componente de ejemplo con código mínimo para la prueba.

**Servicio**

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class HttpService {

  // variables de tipo BehaviorSubject
  // son observables que permitirán a los componentes suscribirse
  // y ser notificados cuando los valores estén listos
  pathPadre = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');
  pathPadreEnServidor = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
 
 cargarRutas(){

   this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/obtenerrutas').subscribe( r => {

     // cuando la respuesta finaliza se llama el método next()
     // para notificar a los suscriptores que hay nuevos
     // valores
     this.pathPadre.next(r[0]);
     this.pathPadreEnServidor.next(r[1]);

   });

 }


}
```

**Componente**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpService } from './http.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: ``
})
export class AppComponent  {
  pathPadre : string;

  constructor(private http : HttpService){
    // llamar el método cargar rutas del servicio
    this.http.cargarRutas();
    // suscribirse al observable http.pathPadre
    // cuando el valor esté listo se asignará a la variable local
    // this.pathPadre
    this.http.pathPadre.subscribe(p => this.pathPadre = p);

  }
}
```

Comment: Me funcionó, pero me marca un error en el componente en la línea  de ```this.http.pathPadre.subscribe(p => this.pathPadre = p);``` , me dice lo siguiente ```Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'BehaviorSubject<string>'.```.

Comment: He editado el contenido de la pregunta principal para que lo puedas ver mejor ordenado.

Comment: `BehaviorSubject` se usa solo en el servicio. Los suscriptores reciben un `string`. En el IndexComponent debe ser `pathPadre : string`.

Comment: Perdona, no me di cuenta de ello en el código que pusiste, lo di por hecho. Muchísimas gracias por tu ayuda, llevaba horas rompiendome la cabeza!